# Swift where class addresses are stored?

Tags: ios, swift

I know structures are stored in stack and class are stored in heap. I read somewhere that class address are stored in stack's too. is it correct ?

Comment: "I read somewhere" should include a link to what you've read so we can understand if you've misunderstood something or the thing you read was incorrect. As stated, this question doesn't mean anything. Yes, a class's address may be stored on the stack. It may also be stored on the heap. Also it may be stored in a register. The address will be stored wherever it is required. Can you make your question more specific? A class address is just a "pointer-sized" integer (i.e. a 64-bit number on most platforms). It's stored in whatever references it.

Comment: its from raywenderlich, I just did not understand it "When you create an instance of a class, your code requests a block of memory on the heap to store the instance itself; that’s the first name and last name inside the instance on the right side of the diagram. It stores the address of that memory in your named variable on the stack; that’s the reference stored on the left side of the diagram."

Comment: local variables are stored on the stack. The variable holds the address of the class you created (it does not hold the actual class).

Comment: The actual data for instances of classes are on the heap.  The reference that you hold that is on the stack (or in registers) is effectively a reference-counted pointer to it (ie, the address of the heap allocation for the instance), though this pointer is hidden from you inside the reference.  The layout depends on whether it's a native Swift class or an `@objc` class.  I don't know the exact lay-out but instances of native Swift classes will contain something like a "vptr" similar to classes in C++ (except in C++ the actual instance data might be on the stack).

Comment: Also, saying that the references are on the stack is assuming that they are local variables or parameters, though many parameters are passed in registers, according to architecture-specific conventions.  If they are properties of a `struct` or `class` then the reference will be on the stack if in an instance of a `struct` or on the heap if in an instance of a `class`.  And if they are global/static variables, then they are in the data segment of the program memory, so neither on the heap nor the stack.